# Passing string/int to label with c# in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, string, xaml, label

I'm making a TCP client and would like it to show the IP and port that is been used.

I have two labels that I would like to be filled with the text of the ip and port been used, these in the code are called serverip_lbl and portno_lbl.

You can see I have tried two different ways to do this, neither give me an error and allow me to compile. However, the labels show nothing on the interface.

```
namespace client
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(); // New instance of TcpClient class of the .Net.Sockets
        string ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 8888;

        private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client.Connect(ipaddress, port); // IP, Port
            serverip_lbl.Content += "" + ipaddress;
            portno_lbl.Content = port;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="client.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:client"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="400">
<Grid>
    <Label x:Name="titleclient_txt" Content="Client" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18.667" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontStyle="Italic" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <Label x:Name="demotitle_txt" Content="Sending a message" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,50,87,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <Label x:Name="server_lbl" Content="Server IP:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <Label x:Name="serverip_lbl" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <Label x:Name="port_lbl" Content="Port:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,146,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <Label x:Name="portno_lbl" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,146,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <Label x:Name="message_lbl" Content="Message:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,199,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="message_txt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" Margin="74,230,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"/>
    <Button x:Name="send_button" Content="Send" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,344,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button x:Name="request_button" Content="Request message" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="125,380,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="137"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: try .Text instead of .Content

Comment: Is `MainWindow_Load` actually attached to the Window's `Loaded` event?

Comment: @Steve Label has no Text property. OP would have to use TextBlocks instead of Labels.

Comment: Label does not contain a definition for '.Text'. It uses content instead as it is a label

Comment: @HJagger95 It doesn't matter if you use Label and set its Content property, or if you use TextBlock and set its Text property.

Comment: show your xaml code plz

Comment: I do not understand what you mean Clemens? Everything in the code is what I have done.

Comment: I mean `<Window ... Loaded="MainWindow_Load">` in the Window's XAML.

Comment: I will upload the XAML

Comment: @HJagger95 exactly as I thought, you never registered the load event

Comment: one other comment, you should look into MVVM design pattern. The way you are doing it is not the right WPF way

Comment: I have added Loaded = "MainWindow_Load" to the XAML, now I get SocketException was unhandled.

Comment: _"now I get SocketException was unhandled"_ -- well, that's a completely different question. Don't make the mistake of turning this into a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: I'm not asking I'm just providing an update to someones suggested fix :) This occurs because the system its connecting to rejects it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because the XAML code did not contain 'Loaded = "MainWindow_Load"'.

Thus, the wpf interface will not have anyway of loading the c# to pass the string into the label.